# Windows 10 PC wakes up on its own, even when the lid is closed

Tags: laptop, windows-10, sleep

I have a laptop which I recently upgraded to windows 10. I am facing an issue with the same symptoms as many others, my laptops wakes up from sleep at ungodly hours at night.

There is a difference though. It happens only when we actually do something around the house, mostly when we turn on or off lights in the middle of the night (typically, I go to the loo, and when i come back its on). This even happens if the laptop lid is closed. I do not remember this happening with windows 8 or 8.1 though..

Should I be worried about any wiring issues in the house or something like that? Else is there a way to atleast keep it from turning on when the lid is shut?

p.s. I know this sounds spooky and many of you might suggest windows update and such, but I have both observed and even tested this.. so unless is a unlikely coincidence, it appears linked to the act of us turning lights on/off

Comment: Have you looked in the eventlog what causes the laptop to wake up ? Also, does it wake up and stay awake or does it go from standby (suspend to ram) to hibernate (suspend to disk) ?

Comment: @kyze Havent yet, if you can point me to a reference for that I can try tonight and get back